# Statically link SDL on Windows (MinGW) / undefined references

Tags: sdl, static-linking

I built SDL (2.0.10) using cmake and now I am trying to link it to my application.

For linking I use **g++ $(OBJS) -L./Path/To/SDL/LibFolder -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2-static -oOut.exe**

When I link it dynamically using SDL2, it works without problems. But I would like to link it statically.
I tried including every library that I found in error log (-lkernel32 -ladvapi32 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lmsvcrt -lole32 -loleaut32 -lsetupapi -lshell32 -luser32 -lversion -lwinmm -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2-static), but it did nothing. I guess I don't understand how this linking stuff works.

It outputs this: (There is more, but I want to keep it simple. There are more undefined references to libraries that I listed above.)

```
./deps/windows/sdl/lib/libSDL2-static.a(SDL_windows.c.obj): In function `WIN_CoInitialize':
D:/Users/alesg/Desktop/comp/SDL-mirror/src/core/windows/SDL_windows.c:76: undefined reference to `__imp_CoInitializeEx'
./deps/windows/sdl/lib/libSDL2-static.a(SDL_windows.c.obj): In function `WIN_CoUninitialize':
D:/Users/alesg/Desktop/comp/SDL-mirror/src/core/windows/SDL_windows.c:95: undefined reference to `__imp_CoUninitialize'
./deps/windows/sdl/lib/libSDL2-static.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_SetupAPI':
D:/Users/alesg/Desktop/comp/SDL-mirror/src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:650: undefined reference to `ImmGetIMEFileNameA'     
D:/Users/alesg/Desktop/comp/SDL-mirror/src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:732: undefined reference to `ImmGetCompositionStringW'  
D:/Users/alesg/Desktop/comp/SDL-mirror/src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:737: undefined reference to `ImmGetCompositionStringW'  
./deps/windows/sdl/lib/libSDL2-static.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_HandleMessage':
D:/Users/alesg/Desktop/comp/SDL-mirror/src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:901: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext'
./deps/windows/sdl/lib/libSDL2-static.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
D:/Users/alesg/Desktop/comp/SDL-mirror/src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:716: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext'
```

Comment: Dependencies have to come after things that depend on them, so `obj_files -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2-static -lkernel32 -ladvapi32 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lmsvcrt -lole32 -loleaut32 -lsetupapi -lshell32 -luser32 -lversion -lwinmm` or something like that.

Comment: This solved it. Thanks.